# Error in -x: invalid argument to unary operator using ggplot 2 multiline code

Tags: r, ggplot2, unary-operator

I am trying to make a forest plot using odds ratios; however, I keep running into a problem.  I get this message "Error in -x: invalid argument to unary operator" when I run the code.

I have checked for extra "+" at the beginning of my lines of code, but cannot seem to find any.

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
ggplot(Limit_water_Round, aes(y = term, x = oddsratio)) +
 geom_point(shape = 18, size = 5) +  
 geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = conflower, xmax = confupper), height = 0.25) +
 geom_vline(xintercept = 1, color = "red", linetype = "solid", cex = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
 scale_y_continuous(name = "", breaks=1:11, labels = Limit_water_Round$term, 
 trans = "reverse") +
  xlab("Odds Ratio (95% CI)") + 
  ylab(" ") + 
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you're encountering might result when there's an issue with the arithmetic operation being performed on your data, not necessarily an issue with the ggplot code itself. From your code, it seems like there is a typo in the `geom_errorbarh`.

Here are a few steps to troubleshoot and resolve your issue:

#### 1. **Correct typos for Horizontal Error Bars:**

Replace `geom_errorbarh` with `geom_errorbar` and adjust your `aes` mappings appropriately. Since you are placing terms on the y-axis and odds ratios on the x-axis, you might not need a horizontal error bar function; the standard `geom_errorbar` might work with your flipped coordinates.

#### 2. **Check Data Types and Values:**

Ensure that all variables (`oddsratio`, `conflower`, `confupper`, and `term`) in your `aes()` mappings are available in your `Limit_water_Round` data frame and have the correct data types and values. The error message might result from trying to perform arithmetic on non-numeric data types or dealing with `NA` or `NULL` values.

#### 3. **Inspect and Debug:**

You might want to print out or inspect your `Limit_water_Round` data frame to ensure it contains what you expect. If possible, try running the `ggplot` code with a subset of your data or with dummy data to identify where the error might be occurring.

#### Suggested/Adjusted Code:

Here's a rough adjustment to your code (you may need to tweak it further based on your specific data and desired output):

```
ggplot(Limit_water_Round, aes(y = term, x = oddsratio)) +
 geom_point(shape = 18, size = 5) +  
 geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = conflower, xmax = confupper), height = 0.25) +
 geom_vline(xintercept = 1, color = "red", linetype = "solid", size = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
 scale_y_continuous(name = "", breaks = 1:11, labels = Limit_water_Round$term) +
 coord_flip() +
 labs(x = "Odds Ratio (95% CI)", y = " ") +
 theme_bw() + 
 theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
       panel.background = element_blank(),
       panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
       panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
       axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
       axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
       axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"),
       axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, colour = "black"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I tried adjusting my code and now get the following error "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale".  My odds ratios are numeric values and were calculated during a binomial logistic regression.  I am not sure how to fix this issue either.

Comment: I tried changing "scale_y_continuous" to "scale_y_discrete", and I get a plot.  However, my axes are flipped with odds ratios on the y axis and the terms on the x axis.  Any tips to fix this or another solution to the above error with the scale being discrete vs continuous?

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you for your help.